# Visual Studio - Solution User Options

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vs-community-edition

Starting a Visual Studio solution causes the error **Unable to load one or more breakpoints**. Moving the file **.vs\SolutionName\v(X).suo** works to fix the error however this is **NOT** an option.

Is there any way to edit this file simply to remove the break point(s) or even regenerate all the Visual Studio settings without the break point(s)?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you use Ctrl+Shift+F9 to remove all breakpoints?

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work